# How to set a border-bottom with radius in all corners on DxTabPage when the menu item is actived?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, devexpress, tailwind-css

I'm using DevExpress and Blazor with tailwind to build a nav menu. Following the UX standards I need set a border-bottom below menu item when is actived. The image below is a example:

[image]

I tried use this css:

```
.dxbl-tabs > .dxbl-scroll-viewer > .dxbl-scroll-viewer-content > ul > li > .dxbl-tabs-item:not(.dxbl-disabled):not(:disabled).dxbl-active, .dxbl-tabs > ul > li > .dxbl-tabs-item:not(.dxbl-disabled):not(:disabled).dxbl-active {
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: inherit !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    border-bottom: solid 2px white !important;
}
```

But the result was radius only bottom corners, and when I up the border-radius the resul is this:

[image]

How I can set the css to have the border-bottom with 2px and the all corners rounded, as in first image?

This is a component that I'm using: https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxTabPage

And this is a code on razor page:

```
<div class="flex-initial">
     <DxTabs CssClass="border-none bg-transparent text-white text-[19.28px] min-w-[110%] active:font-[600]" @bind-ActiveTabIndex="@ActiveTabIndex">
          <DxTabPage Text="Global Production Schedule"
                     CssClass="custom-font-menu-item mx-[6px] px-0 pb-[3px] pt-0 font-medium before:font-[600] hover:font-[600] active:font-[600]" />
          <DxTabPage Text="Base Models"
                     CssClass="custom-font-menu-item mx-[6px] px-0 pb-[3px] pt-0 font-medium before:font-[600] hover:font-[600] active:font-[600]" />
          <DxTabPage Text="Edition Models"
                     CssClass="custom-font-menu-item mx-[6px] px-0 pb-[3px] pt-0 font-medium before:font-[600] hover:font-[600] active:font-[600]" />
     </DxTabs>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is not a border per say, you need either a composed element (not just border under your div) below the text, a image border at the bottom, or a svg below the text.

If you want to use border (composed element) you can that with the following:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/lM1Sc6eod3

which is a fully rounded border div with a black bg.

Comment: Yes , finally I decide use a tag span inside of DxTabPage component, and to keep the clean code, I isolated the component on external file. But thank's for the answer and I thought amazing the tailwind play, I still don´t knowed, always used bootstrap and I'm newer with tailwind.